# why this type of error comes in DevTools failed to load SourceMap

Tags: javascript-engine

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/bootstrap.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvw8P.png)

Comment: What you provided us is an access to your local bootstrap file, which means that we can't access it (see - http://127.0.0.1 is your local address).

But, what this looks like is a `404` error - which means there's probably a bootstrap file that is missing and you're trying to access it. Check your `<script>` tags in headers of the HTML index file.

If you can show us your `index.html` - we'll be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't caused by your code,

From your Chrome browser, Go to DevTool Settings by pressing f12 key, then clicking the gear icon [image: gear icon]

in the upper right corner.

Disable the checkbox:

- Enable JavaScript source maps
- Enable CSS source maps

[image]

Then reload your browser.

For other browser, find **Source** setting after press f12